# Magento 2 - Adminhtml Grid Template

Tags: magento-2.1, adminhtml

I am overriding the Adminhtml Sales Order Create Items Grid template by using a layout in my custom module:

`views/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name='items_grid>
            <action method='setTemplate'>
                <argument name='template' xsi:type='string'>Vendor_Module::order/create/items/grid.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

The problem I am facing is that when the page is loaded via AJAX:
1. Click "Create New Order"
2. Click on a customer
3. Page loads via AJAX and shows the grid.

The grid template that loads is the base grid template (`Magento_Sales/view/templates/order/create/items/grid.phtml`). If I refresh the page or enter the page directly, it loads the overridden template.

My question is: Where does this template get loaded first and how do I prevent it from loading, or how do I force my template to load every time.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override this handle too

```
sales_order_create_load_block_items.xml
```

for ajax call set  template here too

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion and there was no change to sales order create page. Here is my code: 

 `<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
     <body>
         <referenceBlock name="items_grid">
          <action method='setTemplate'>
                 <argument name='template' xsi:type='string'>Vendor_Module::order/create/items/grid.phtml</argument>
             </action>
         </referenceBlock>
     </body>
 </page>`

Comment: @AlexBlock have you solved that issue ?

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to override below three files:

1. sales_order_create_index.xml,
2. sales_order_create_load_block_data.xml,
3. sales_order_create_load_block_items.xml